# Why are these prefix characters more

Tags: jenkins, ant, jmeter

I was building jenkins + ant + jmeter framework, encountered the problem is jenkins parameters passed to jmeter Why a parameter(fieldparam) will be more prefix(-Japi.fieldparam=)??? Proceed as follows:
[image]

[image]

[image][image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: In ant what is your jvm.arg?

Comment: jvm.arg=-Xmx600m @user7294900

Comment: After debugging I found the second parameter caused by the parameter is not too long? If you can replace the short characters can be normal, and why? "{\" MallID \ ": 10030, \" Mobile \ ": \" 13xxxxxx \ ", \" Pwd \ ": \" 1111l \ ", \" VCode \ ": \" \ ", \" LoginType \ " : 1, \ "OauthID \": null, \ "Keyword \": \ "\", \ "Scene \": 4, \ "GraphicType \": 2, \ "Header \": {\ "Token \ : Null}} "

Answer (score 0):

As far as it can be seen from the above screenshots your current configuration is good. Most likely you have an override of your `api.fieldparam` property somewhere (where you tried to get it running via [-J command-line argument](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)) so inspect your Jenkins configuration and look for `-Japi.fieldparam` there.

It worth also checking the following environment variables values:

- `ANT_OPTS`
- `ANT_ARGS`

See [Running Apache Ant](https://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html) for more information on executing Ant and [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) to learn more about JMeter properties and ways of setting and overriding them.

Comment: After debugging I found the second parameter caused by the parameter is not too long? If you can replace the short characters can be normal, and why? "{\" MallID \ ": 10030, \" Mobile \ ": \" 13xxxxxx \ ", \" Pwd \ ": \" 1111l \ ", \" VCode \ ": \" \ ", \" LoginType \ " : 1, \ "OauthID \": null, \ "Keyword \": \ "\", \ "Scene \": 4, \ "GraphicType \": 2, \ "Header \": {\ "Token \ : Null}} " @Dmitri T